# Error on Android Handler update interface

Tags: android, android-handler

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        ReturnShow.setText(sMsg);//ReturnShow EditText
        ReturnShow.setSelection(ReturnShow.length());
    }
};

class ReadThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        sMsg = "...";
        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
    }
}
```

Everytime I run, the `setText` line will have error, I can't figure out why?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `ReturnShow` is initialized before setting it..

Something like..

```
ReturnShow = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer，but I have Assign this value in OnCreate,the error is still on

Comment: the error is in ReturnShow.setText(sMsg) or ReturnShow.setSelection(ReturnShow.length())?

Comment: oh.i'm stupid ,i found the error,`ReturnShow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ResultShow);` I use a incorrect ID here.thanks for your answer.